# Chrome extension to pop out a tab

Tags: chrome

Is there a Google Chrome extension to pop out a tab into a separate window? Similar to how one can pop-out a conversation in Hangouts on Google+. Specific extensions exist for YouTube videos, but I'd like something more general that works on any tab.

Natively in Chrome, when a window pops up, you have the option to right click on the title bar and choose "show as tab" to make this window become a tab.

[image]

What I'd like is the exact opposite of this feature: right clicking a tab, and popping it out.

I could - for example - use that in combination with an "Always on Top" and "Transparency" options to:

- watch a video lecture in a tiny window while taking notes in a document,
- keep an eye on the progress of an upload while browsing other pages, or
- look at the manual of a command while typing a code

without having to tile the windows or drag them across monitors. Plus, having the tab in every window clutters the view and is unnecessary. Something like a Hangouts conversation window would be perfect. I'd settle for a workaround to hide the tab/address bars in windows containing single tabs since that would accomplish the same result.

I use Windows 7, Windows 8.1, and Xubuntu. So an extension that's OS-independent would be ideal, but one that only works on Windows is also great.

---

EDIT:

> So what do you mean by pop-out? Separating a tab from a group of tabs?

A pop-out is a different type of window. Here is an example from Gmail Compose window:

Pop-out with its context menu:

[image][image]

Dragged out with its context menu:

[image][image]

As you can see, there is way less clutter in the pop out Window. Additionally, the context menu has more useful options, including: **Always on Top**, **Transparency**, and **Minimize to Tray**

I hope the difference is clear now

Comment: So what do you mean by pop-out? Separating a tab from a group of tabs?

Comment: I edited my question with screenshots of the difference

Comment: So, you want the end result of using the javascript `window.open(location.href, "detab", "toolbar=0");` ?

Comment: Have you considered making a bookmark out of the above javascript? You can just click that and it will do the process. If not, I could make an extension with the javascript.

Comment: I'm on my phone right now, but before I told you about the bookmark, I tested it. Press ctrl+d and change the 'address' to the JavaScript. It should work. If not, I'll quickly make an extension for you :)

Comment: Ok, I've tried it again, looks like it doesn't work (?). Don't know why. I'll make that extension before the end of the day :) (just got home)

Comment: Before I get on with the extension, could you make sure that this javascript is what you want? I just tried it again and compared it to your screenshot. I noticed that the options 'priority', 'transparency', 'always on top' and 'mimimize to tray' were not there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want by using some simple Javascript:

`window.open(location.href, "detab", "toolbar=0", "width=500, height=500");`

I got the Javascript from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25538739/3541881).

You can make a bookmark with this code:

To do this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> *(or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on OSX)* + <kbd>D</kbd>. On the resulting popup, press `Edit`. Change the `URL` to:

`javascript:window.open(location.href, "detab", "toolbar=0", "width=500, height=500");`

Make the name something like `open as popup`. **Note: *Copy and Paste* the above code - you need to have the `javascript:` prefix for this to work in Chrome**. You can edit the numbers for width and height to what you want them to be. This will make the popup open in that size.